# Inserting chart inside Razor view removes all other content from generated HTML, disconnects Browser Link Dashboard, disables source view in browser

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have inseted chart in my Razor View. Before that it was displayed in correctly.

I have inserted this chart:

```
<div>
    @{
        var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
            .AddTitle("Chart Title")
            .AddSeries(
                name: "Employee",
                xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
                yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
            .Write();
    }

    @*}*@
</div>
```

after that only visible content in the website is this chart and the generated view looks like this(everything else disappeared).

[image]

I cannot open the source of the website in the browser(only F12 works), also it makes Browser Link Dashboard lose the connection with browser.

How can I display this chart as any other element in the Razor view?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create a separate view in which to put the chart code and then call a controller method which returns a view as an image source. Example:

View content (the view in which you want the chart):

```
...code...
<!--Graph-->
<img src='@Url.Action("ChartMain", "Subject")'/>
...rest of code...
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult ChartMain()
{
    //*****Your data*****//
    ViewBag.Data = data;
    ViewBag.Names = names;
    return View();
}
```

View content for ChartMain:

```
@{
       var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
       .AddTitle("Chart Title")
       .AddSeries(
          name: "Employee",
          xValue:  @ViewBag.Names,
          yValues: ViewBag.Names)
       .Write();
     }
```